# How to apply CSS rotate transition around glyph's vertical middle or centerpoint

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, glyph

I have a hidden panel that sits off-screen until a `div` gets clicked (see attached, runnable code snippet).

When this `div` is clicked, the panel comes on screen and the `div` contents (a single glyph or character) are rotated 180 degrees.

The problem is that rotation origin is around some point other than the vertical middle of the glyph. When rotation occurs, the glyph moves up several pixels.

How can I measure the glyph attributes and set the rotation origin, so that, when it rotates, it rotates around the vertical middle or center of the glyph?

```js
var show_panel = function() {
 var e = document.getElementById("panel");
 if (e.classList) {
  e.classList.toggle("show");
 }
    else {
     var classes = e.className;
     if (classes.indexOf("show") >= 0) {
      e.className = classes.replace("show", "");
     }
     else {
      e.className = classes + " show";
     }
    }
};
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: system, -apple-system, ".SFNSDisplay-Regular", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", sans-serif !important;
}

#panel {
   width: 300px;
   /* border: 2px solid rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.0933); */
   background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.0933);
   position: fixed;
   top: 60px;
   left: -275px;
   padding: 5px;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#panel.show {
   left: -5px;
}

#panel .controller {
   position: absolute;
   right: 5px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: black;
   font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#panel.show .controller {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <p class="panel_description">Click on the "x" to trigger showing the panel. Note how the "x" does not rotate on the vertical midpoint of the glyph, but instead moves upwards</p>
    <div id="panel">
      <div onclick="show_panel();" class="controller">x</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in IE, because you didn't include the unprefixed `transition` and `transform` properties...

Comment: I'm mainly interested in browsers that support current standards.

Comment: So you want to support current standards, yet you use outdated vendor prefixes. Mhm, makes perfect sense. What you *mean* is that you're prejudiced against IE because you haven't touched it since IE6 and assume it must still be as shitty as it was then. Believe me, it is *not*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by setting css property`transform-origin: 50% 50%` it will provide transformation around the center of the element. I hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for the help — with some tweaking to the y-percentage this worked better.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: don't use a glyph when you want an icon.

An icon can very easily be made to be rotationally symmetrical, making it so that when flipped over it will not "move up".

To see exactly why your "x" is not symmetrical, check this out:

```css
.x {
  display: inline-block;
  background: pink;
}
.flipped {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="x">x</div>
<div class="x flipped">x</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking for an answer that uses glyphs (icon fonts, ultimately).

Comment: Then make sure they are rotationally symmetrical. `x` is not, as you can clearly see.